# Expanding friendly url, mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using modx, which is a cms system. It has a friendly url-option and uses a .htaccess like this.

```
# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If makes the url look like: mysite.com/about and mysite.com/about/contact

I'd like to expand this .htaccess, so I can write myste.com/about/2 without the page 2 actually existing. I'd like to have the ability to access this in a get-variable. Can this be done? I have no knowledge at this area whatsoever.

Comment: What does the non-friendly URL look like when you paginate? Is there a query string parameter like **p=2**? thus making the URL look like http://mysite.com/index.php?q=about/contact&p=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* do this in your .htaccess, but a better way might be to create a plugin that fires on the OnPageNotFound event.

myste.com/about/2 does not exist so it will trigger your plugin which will run before sending the user to the 404 page. In this case, you can can split the /2 from the end of the url and use it to pull in your data or send the user to a different page instead of going to 404.

Does that make sense? It's a bit difficult to contribute more without knowing exactly what you want to do :)

Comment: Sorry for late acceptance, but this is a great answer. We ended up doing it this way on many projects. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, it's the recommended way to handle this. I have a site with thousands of pages which are run off only three MODX resources, all routed using a plugin fired on OnPageNotFound.