# how to do a regular expression for the .htaccess file for tags in modx?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, modx, modx-revolution

I need a regular expression for next url:

sitio.com/blog/tag.html?tag=tecnology
convert to:
sitio.com/blog/tag/tecnology

note: I activated the friendly urls for modx.

Comment: What ? So you want the same URL ? Doesn't make sense ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way to do this using MODX inbuilt functionality.

Create a plugin that fires on OnPageNotFound and parses the 'not found' url (sitio.com/blog/tag/tecnology) into the format you're expecting (sitio.com/blog/tag.html?tag=tecnology). If the parsed format matches an existing MODX resource you can then redirect to it.

http://forums.modx.com/index.php/topic,41502.msg249684.html#msg249684

Comment: would have to create a resource for each insert value... but i haven't only one element for result. And tags aren't statics

Comment: No, quite the opposite - you don't need to create any more resources. The plugin simply 'decodes' your SEO friendly url and splits it back into the ?tag= version, then sends the user to your tag.html page.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429034/expanding-friendly-url-mod-rewrite/8477402#8477402